# Visual Studio Preview を macOS にインストールする方法はありますか？

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, macos

`Xamarin Live Player`を使いたく Visual Studio Preview を Mac で使おうとしたのですが、Windows用のインストーラーしか見つかりませんでした。

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/

おそらくMacではPreview版が使えないということなのだと思うのですが、「できない。」と明示されている部分も見つからなかったのでインストールできる方法があるなら知りたく質問いたしました。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Xamarin Live Player Setup](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/live/install/?ide=xs#2._Get_the_Visual_Studio_for_Mac_Preview_or_for_Windows)によると

> Xamarin Live Player requires:
>   - OS X 10.11, macOS 10.12, or greater
>   - Visual Studio for Mac ([Alpha channel preview](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/#xamarinstudio))
>   - A Mac and a device on the same WiFi network

とのことですので、Visual Studio 2017 [15.4 Preview](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/#visualstudio2017) or newerだけでなく、Visual Studio for Mac ([Alpha channel preview](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/#xamarinstudio))でも動作するようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/update の方法でアップデートできました。

Answer (score 0):

PreviewはあくまでVisual Studio 2017のリリース形態ですので当然にWindowsしかサポートしていないと思います。